# sum of $row based on specific time field rather than just total

Tags: php, mysql, sum, cumulative-sum, subtotal

This code works just fine to display a list of reservations for a given day and sums the guest and table counts just fine for the entire day. Sums all reservations returned.

What I am trying to do or figure out is a way to get totals based on specific time intervals. 
For example how many guests and tables at 8:00, 9:00, 10:00, etc....

I can see where the sums are calculated, but need help adding a way to add a variable to look at the reservation_time and sum by hour rather than just daily total.

```
        $tablesum ++;
        $guestsum += $row->reservation_pax;
<?php echo $guestsum;?>&nbsp;&nbsp;<?php echo _guest_summary;?>
```

The full code that pulls in the data and then sums it up in total:

```
<?php
    // Clear reservation variable
    $reservations ='';

    if ($_SESSION['page'] == 1) {
        $reservations = querySQL('all_reservations');
    }else{
        $reservations = querySQL('reservations');
    }

    // reset total counters
    $tablesum = 0;
    $guestsum = 0;

    if ($reservations) {

        //start printing out reservation grid
        foreach($reservations as $row) {
            // reservation ID
            $id = $row->reservation_id;
            $_SESSION['reservation_guest_name'] = $row->reservation_guest_name;
            // check if reservation is tautologous
            $tautologous = querySQL('tautologous');

        echo "<tr id='res-".$id."'>";
        echo "<td";
        // daylight coloring
        if ($row->reservation_time > $daylight_evening){
            echo " class='evening noprint'";
        }else if ($row->reservation_time > $daylight_noon){
            echo " class='afternoon noprint'";
        }else if ($row->reservation_time < $daylight_noon){
            echo " class='morning noprint'";
        }

        echo " style='width:10px !important; padding:0px;'>&nbsp;</td>";
        echo "<td id='tb_time'";
        // reservation after maitre message
        if ($row->reservation_timestamp > $maitre['maitre_timestamp'] && $maitre['maitre_comment_day']!='') {
            echo " class='tautologous' title='"._sentence_13."' ";
        }
        echo ">";
        echo "<strong>".formatTime($row->reservation_time,$general['timeformat'])."</strong></td>";
        echo "<td id='tb_pax'><strong class='big'>".$row->reservation_pax."</strong>&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class='noprint'>";
        $tablesum ++;
        $guestsum += $row->reservation_pax;
        }
    }
    ?>

    <?php echo $guestsum;?>&nbsp;&nbsp;<?php echo _guest_summary;?>
```

Ok I am getting close: was able to get it to total and display... though I need to narrow by one more parameter.  That is giving me the total guest count (reservation_pax) for all reservations. I need to do it by the given date or session.  The page shows only reservation for the date selected, but script counts all days with reservations at 8:00.

Just need help to narrow by session page is already creating for specific date being viewed.

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT SUM(reservation_pax) FROM reservations WHERE reservation_time = '8:00'"); 
if($result === FALSE) {
die(mysql_error()); // TODO: better error handling
}

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{

   echo $row['SUM(reservation_pax)'];
}
```

Comment: Since I got some feedback that this was vague and not vary familiar with php.  I just need to be able to count guest based on of the column reservation_time.  SO I guess to clarify what I am trying to do is add the total in reservation_pax for or based on a specific reservation_time in another table row.  I have read several items, posts and php tutorials, but can't seem to get them applied in this file or to work.

Comment: Doing some more research... could I do something like this? ` SELECT reservation_time, sum( reservation_pax ) as total_mark FROM`reservations` GROUP BY reservation_time `  I tried but can't seem to figure out how to include in the php file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT SUM(reservation_pax) FROM reservations WHERE reservation_time = '8:00:00' AND reservation_date = '2014-10-27' AND reservation_hidden ='0'") ; 
if($result === FALSE) {
    die(mysql_error()); // TODO: better error handling
}

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
   echo $row['SUM(reservation_pax)'];
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to generate series with time interval, assuming you have some table with more then 15 rows (I called it lookup_table) you can do this with uservars.

```
SELECT d.starttime, d.endtime, COUNT(r.id) AS total
FROM
    (
     SELECT
        @starttime := @starttime + INTERVAL 1 HOUR starttime,
        @endtime := @endtime + INTERVAL 1 HOUR endtime
     FROM
        lookup_table
     CROSS JOIN (SELECT @starttime := CURRENT_DATE + INTERVAL 7 HOUR,
                        @endtime := CURRENT_DATE + INTERVAL 8 HOUR - INTERVAL 1 SECOND) v
     LIMIT 15
    ) d
LEFT JOIN
    reservations r
    ON r.reservation_time BETWEEN d.starttime AND d.endtime
GROUP BY d.starttime, d.endtime
```

If you need to filter out some data from reservations, you need to add that to the join condition.

This is based on the information you provided (which isn't much).

Comment: Thanks for the response I think this is much more savvy than I need. As I don't know much about php I am reading a lot. I vaguely understand that currently the script is adding up all the number of guests in the table for that day and giving me the total guest. What i want to do is have individual totals for each available slot (time). So I don' need intervals per say or maybe clueless... I just need to be able to count guest based on of the available reservation slots being in this case 8:00, 8:10, 8:20 and so on.  I am trying to add a total in reservation_pax for a specific reservation_time

Comment: Can you provide the DDL for the table (with `SHOW CREATE TABLE`) with some sample data and the required output. What the subquery aliased with d does is generating time slots (`2014-10-26 08:00:00 | 2014-10-26 08:59:59 ...  2014-10-26 22:00:00 | 2014-10-26 22:59:59`). Then the reservation table is joined on reservation_time between that interval, assuming reservation_time is datetime datatype

Comment: Not sure how to post this as comment so will try to make it readable by adding a few comments...apologies if not correct way to do this. reservation_id | reservation_date | reservation_time | reservation_pax

Comment: 1 | 7/31/2014 | 8:00:00 | 1 ....
2 | 7/31/2014 | 8:00:00 | 4  .....

19 | 7/30/2014 | 8:10:00 |       3.....
20 |7/30/2014 | 8:10:00         | 2

Comment: could I do something simple like this?   $guestsum2 += $row->`reservation_pax` WHERE `reservation_time` = '8:00';  After doing some reasearch it looks simple, but I can't get the condition to work...it throws error, so something wrong in the way I am coding.  Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '`', expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or '{' or '$' in

Comment: <?php $query = 'SELECT SUM(`reservation_pax`) FROM `reservations` WHERE `reservation_time` = 8:00' ; 
$result = mysql_query($query);

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    echo $row['SUM(reservation_pax)'];
}
?>